# How can I reinterpret a byte as an integer in java?

Tags: java

I have a problem with conversions of different types.
In my code I am trying to use bytes and then convert them to an integer to be able to write x amount of bits from the integer to a storage of a kind.

The problem is that when I have a negative number as byte and I convert it to an integer, the bit representation as an integer has all the leading bits set as 1.
So when I try to save for example 10 bits from the integer, I get the leading bits as 1 instead of 0 as I expected.

Is there a way to reinterpret the byte as an integer while keeping the bit representation the same? I do not need to care about the actual numerical value of the integer.

From C++ I am used to having unsigned values which would prevent this issue, but now I am at loss with how to deal with this in java being limited to signed integers.

Example:

```
/*
    decimal: -28
    as byte: 11100100
    as integer: 11111111111111111111111111100100
    needed/expected integer: 00000000000000000000000011100100
*/
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class MyClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((byte)-28));
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/VE960u

Comment: What do you mean you want to keep the bit representation the same but you don't care about the numerical value? They are the same thing.

Comment: "Is there a way to reinterpret the byte as an integer while keeping the bit representation the same" - you might intuitively think of the operation you're trying to perform as "keeping the bit representation the same", but it's really not. The int has a bunch of bits the byte just doesn't have, and filling those bits with zeros isn't "keeping the bit representation the same" any more than sign-extension is.

Comment: @Zarwan The idea is to keep only the bits set in the integer that are set in the byte. When that is done, the numerical value/interpretion of the integer is different than what the byte was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourInt = yourByte & 255;
```

Just mask out the undesired bits.